# URL permissions

Tags: uri, users

I have some nodes which I want to hide from anonymous users when they access via a direct URL e.g. /node/1275.

However if someone accesses this via the URL alias which is an md5 hash I want to allow anonymous users to access it. This is so that the node is essentially available only to people I give the link to.

How would I achieve this? Ideally I'd like to avoid installing more modules.

---

EDIT:

Here's the complete solution that I used in my custom module. As well as the access check it contains a new filter type that generates a md5 for each node, which you can use in the URL alias patterns page.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter
 */
function newsletter_access_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'newsletter_access_check_node_access';
}

/**
 * Custom menu access callback for node/%node
 */
function newsletter_access_check_node_access($op, $node){

  // Note $op and $node are passed in default node_menu access arguments
  if ($op == 'view' && isset($node->nid)) {
     if($node->type == "newsletter") {
            // Allow access to anon if request_uri contains specific hash
            if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
              $hash = md5(drupal_get_private_key() . $node->nid);
              // request_uri includes alias
              $request = explode('/', request_uri());
              if (in_array($hash, $request)) {
                return TRUE;
              } else {
                return FALSE;
              }
            }
        }
      }
  // Fallback to allow regular node_access checks
  return node_access($op, $node);
}


function newsletter_access_token_info() {
  $types['my_tokens'] = array(
    'name' => t("My Tokens"),
    'description' => t("My Token Category"),
  );

  $tokens['my_md5'] = array(
    'name' => t("Unique MD5 Hash"),
    'description' => t("The md5 hash unique for each node."),
  );

  return array(
    'types' => $types,
    'tokens' => array(
      'my_tokens' => $tokens,
    ),
  );

}

function newsletter_access_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {

  $replacements = array();

  if ($type == 'my_tokens') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'my_md5':
          $replacements[$original] =  md5(drupal_get_private_key() . $data['node']->nid);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}

?>
```

Comment: looks good, the only thing I wonder about is making the hash a bit more secure. I added that MD5 one as a temporary example, but it would perhaps be better to use an additional salt paramter and/or perhaps a function like `hash_hmac` instead, otherwise fine.

Comment: Wrapping the $node->nid in an additional MD5 could suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter
 */
function MY_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'MY_MODULE_check_node_access';
}

/**
 * Custom menu access callback for node/%node
 */
function MY_MODULE_check_node_access($op, $node){
  // Note $op and $node are passed in default node_menu access arguments
  if ($op == 'view' && isset($node->nid)) {
    // Allow access to anon if request_uri contains specific hash
    if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
      $hash = md5(drupal_get_private_key() . md5($node->nid));
      // request_uri includes alias
      $request = explode('/', request_uri());
      if (in_array($hash, $request)) {
        return TRUE;
      } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
  // Fallback to allow regular node_access checks
  return node_access($op, $node);
}
```

Comment: that's a really flexible solution, and i could probably use that for a number of other permissions issues! i didn't know how to use access callbacks so it's good to know how to use it.

Comment: You're welcome, note I updated to add a condition for authenticated users to fallback to regular node_access. When you add a custom access callback, it's often a good idea to fallback to the original access callback if your conditions pass.

Comment: I think $items needs to be &$items to work (for other people's benefit this means the value get passed back)

Comment: @AlexLee thanks, I think you're right. It was written on the fly. Code adjusted.

Comment: hi if some one drupal_http_request /node/1275 will he able to retrieve node data?

Comment: No, without the hash, it will be access denied.

Comment: if they are logged in they can access the node at that url, if they are not access is denied. i've added the complete working code i used for my module under the question text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in the template.php? what if you do something like:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook){
   if((arg(0) == 'node') && (!$user->uid)){
      //redirect
   }
}
```